# Is there a way of saving the output when running a program in Qbasic?

Tags: output, text-files, qbasic

Is there a way of saving the output when running a program in Qbasic?

The thing is, the program I run has a lot of output. I've already adjusted the screen size. While that can work sometimes, even that has its limitations with too much output. For some reason, I can't scroll the run screen up or down or anything.

Perhaps there is also a way to change the text size of output. But again, limitations here as well.

Therefore, is there a way to save the output to a file type like `.txt`,
`.nfo`, etc. where I can read it in an easier to use format?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Instead of printing to the screen, print to a file, with something like this:

```
OPEN “file.txt” FOR OUTPUT AS #1
FOR linenum = 0 TO numoflines -1
  PRINT #1, line$
NEXT linenum
CLOSE #1
END
```

Comment: Your `FOR-NEXT` example could confuse the OP even more! You should indicate that *line$* has to be filled with new content once per iteration. Or else write it using an array like `PRINT #1, line$(linenum)`.

Answer (score 0):

Pl. do not confuse with "Line$" only, instead use, [variable1,Variable2...] etc.
One can place some spacing formats like, Semicolon (;), comma(,); tab(n) or spc(n) command(s) for clarity and readability OR Locate Row,Column command for better printing.